# Solution Packaging Images

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package

I have a solution package (sandboxed) for branding. All my images are deployed to the Style Library.

I deploy the solution package and I can see all images inside Style Library. I can access the images in my masterpage but when I want to insert an image to a page, I cannot see any image inside the Style Library.
I see all images in Sharepoint Designer pointing to the library. If I insert another image with designer I can choose it from the interface, but none of those I install via solution package.

Why?

Comment: This topic helped me to solve my problem.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39826/error-when-deploying-module-with-ghostableinlibrary-files

Answer (score 0):

can i ask, why you deploying the imsages to Style library?
Style Library basically used for CSS files, basic images, and XSL styles etc. For regular images I would recomend to deployed the images Into Site collection Images Library.

Comment: Hi, I'm deploying to Style Library because those images are to be used in many pages in the portal. They are basic icons and small images mostly used in masterpages but can be used in content pages also.